# Build subproject using Gradle Wrapper while keeping Docker image slim

Tags: docker, gradle, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a multi-project Gradle build that I want to build and test on CircleCI, and then upload the resulting images to Google Container Repository.

The project is setup with a Gradle Wrapper (gradlew) in the root directory. From the root directory I can call for example

`./gradlew :backend:api:build`

This builds the subproject and produces a fat jar. This fat jar is what I intend to put inside the final Docker image and deploy. To keep my Docker images as small as possible I have placed a Dockerfile in each subproject directory. What I want to do is only copy for example `/root/backend/api` into a Docker image, and build that subproject. This is where I run into trouble. When I attempt to

`RUN ./gradlew :backend:api:build`

inside the Dockerfile placed in `root/backend/api` it results in `/bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: not found`. This is expected as `./gradlew` is only available in the root directory. I'm trying to understand if there's a best practice in this scenario. A few options I've considered are:

1. Put `./gradlew` files in each subproject directory. Feels redundant and bad.
2. Copy the entire repo into the image, rather than just `/backend/api`. This results in a much bigger image, which also feels redundant.
3. Skip using the wrapper. Less predictable results, I think?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!